# PropertyInfo GetValue throwing error during recursion

Tags: c#, reflection, propertyinfo

I am getting "Object does not match target type" when I try to retrieve the value of a object at runtime in my C# program.

```
public void GetMyProperties(object obj)
{
  foreach(PropertyInfo pinfo in obj.GetType().GetProperties())
  {
    if(!Helper.IsCustomType(pinfo.PropertyType))
    {
      string s = pinfo.GetValue(obj, null); //throws error during recursion call
      propArray.Add(s);
    }
    else
    {
      object o = pinfo.PropertyType;
      GetMyProperties(o);
    }
  }
}
```

I pass an object of my Class BrokerInfo which has one property of type Broker which inturn has properties - FirstName and LastName (all strings for simplicity).

```
- BrokerInfo
  - Broker
    - FirstName
    - LastName
```

I am trying to recursively checking for custom types and trying to get their values. I am able to do for something like:

```
- Broker
  - FirstName
  - LastName
```

Please help.

Update: Was able to resolve it w/ the help of leppie: here is the modified code.

```
public void GetMyProperties(object obj)
{
  foreach(PropertyInfo pinfo in obj.GetType().GetProperties())
  {
    if(!Helper.IsCustomType(pinfo.PropertyType))
    {
      string s = pinfo.GetValue(obj, null); 
      propArray.Add(s);
    }
    else
    {
      object o = pinfo.GetValue(obj, null);
      GetMyProperties(o);
    }
  }
}
```

IsCustom is my method to check if the type is custome type or not. Here is the code:

```
public static bool IsCustomType(Type type)
{
    //Check for premitive, enum and string
    if (!type.IsPrimitive && !type.IsEnum && type != typeof(string))
    {
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

Comment: Can you please post the code for `Helper.IsCustomType`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Why are you drilling down on the type, instead of the instance?

Specifically here:

```
  object o = pinfo.PropertyType;
  GetMyProperties(o);
```

It should look something like:

```
  var o = pinfo.GetValue(obj, null);
  GetMyProperties(o);
```

Comment: @thanks leppie, I guess I was doing it wrong :) Will try this soon.

Comment: leppie, perfect solution. I have posted the modified code that worked above. Though getting another issue now but will post it separately. Thanks!